# Dealing with CSV Source Connector

Tags: csv, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Are there some examples of configuration for CSV Source Connector, especially dealing with Schema Generation? I didn't find any.

Comment: Which connector, specifically? spooldir?

Comment: Yes the spooldir CSV Source Connector (com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector)